# Salesforce Lightning - Selenium UI Tests- Locate element | Locate element from frame source

Tags: lightning-web-components, selenium

I am using Selenium and Java for Salesforce UI test automation. On the Field Service page, Gantt chart and Service Appointment feature is there.
Both these features are in a frame source. While locating the element using using xpath/css, element is located, but as its in frame source, until inspect the element by right clicking, its not finding it. Even tried moving to frame, but these elements are under div and not frame.

This is failing the test during test run.

Any suggestions on how to deal with such objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by switching to iFrame. It took some time to find the iframe.
`driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);`